# How to convert column that has text element to column of numerics before modelling

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataset that has
 [image: columns with text in it]
How can I change `Elements` and `Area` with numbers before modelling

Answer (score 1):

If need [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) for strings columns use:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
```